# array/data set constructor questions

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, constructor

I'm creating a program which takes a user's info and outputs the min, max, average, sum, and counts how many values were in it. I'm really struggling to figure out how to create default constructor of 100 items and the array size which the user is supposed to define.

- Create a new DataSet object.  The client creating the object specifies the maximum number 
  of items that can be added to the set.  (Write a constructor with one int parameter.)
- Also write a default constructor which creates a DataSet capable of handling 100 items.
- Add an integer data item to a DataSet.  If the maximum number of items have already been added to the set, the item is simply ignored.

Here is my code

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class DataSet {

        private int count; // Number of numbers that have been entered.
        private double sum; // The sum of all the items that have been entered.
        private double min;
        private double max;

        //Adds numbers to dataset.    
            public void addDatum(double num) {
            count++;
            sum += num;
            if (count == 1){
            min = num;
            max = num;
        } else if (num < min){
            min = num;
        } else if (num > max){
            max = num;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Return number of items entered into the dataset.     
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    //Return the sum of all the numbers that have been entered.   
    public double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    //Return the average of all the numbers that have been entered.       
    public double getAvg() {
        return sum / count;
    }

    //return Maximum value of data entered.
    public double getMax(){
        return max;
    }

    //return Minimum value of data entered.
    public double getMin(){
        return min;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        DataSet calc = new DataSet();
        double nextnumber = 0;

        while (true){
            System.out.print("Enter the next number(0 to exit): ");
            nextnumber = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (nextnumber == 0)
                break;
            calc.addDatum(nextnumber);
        }

        System.out.println("Min = "+calc.getMin());
        System.out.println("Max = "+calc.getMax());
        System.out.println("Mean = "+calc.getAvg());       
        System.out.println("Count = "+calc.getCount());
        System.out.println("Sum = "+calc.getSum());
    }

} //end class DataSet
```

Comment: so what is your question? are you having trouble saving and checking a limit?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for declaring an array is `type[] name;` (there are variants, but this is the most common)

So an int array is declared as thus:

```
int[] someIntegers;
```

Creating a new array can be done several ways. The normal way is to create an empty array with all elements initialised to their default value (zero or false for primitive datatypes, and null for object arrays). The syntax is:

```
someIntegers = new int[4]; // ie. [0, 0, 0, 0] 
// or
int n = ...; // intitalise n some how
someIntegers = new int[n]; 
// this way we can get different length arrays at runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a variable to hold the max amount of numbers.

```
int max = 0;
```

Then you would need the two constructors:

```
Dataset() {
    max = 100;
}

Dataset(int max) {
    this.max = max;
}
```

Then when you get the input, you have to check if you have reached the number limit before you do anything.

```
System.out.print("Enter the next number(0 to exit): ");
nextnumber = scanner.nextDouble();
if (count < max) {
    if (nextnumber == 0) {
        break;
    }
    calc.addDatum(nextnumber);
}
```

Comment: My response is not using an array since you seem to just be tracking the max, min, sum and average without the need to store every number that was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above does not contain any constructors, so only the default DataSet() constructor is available. In your DataSet class, you need to define both constructors to meet your requirements. In addition you will need to create a collection type (ie an array of ints) for storing the numbers added to the dataset (this seems to be part of your requirements). With the code below, when you create an instance of the DataSet class in your main method, you can create it with the default 100 elements by saying

```
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
```

or you can create it with a user specified number of elements like

```
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet(30); //for thirty elements in the array
```

```
public class DataSet {

 int[] myArray;
 public DataSet() //Zero parameters constructor
 {
   //initialize your array to 100 elements here
   myArray = new int[100];  //the array can hold 100 elements
 }

 public DataSet(int max) //One parameter constructor
 {
  //initialize your array to 'max' elements here
  myArray = new int[max]; //the array can hold max number of elements
 }

 public void AddNum(int num)
 {
   //logic to add number to the array here :P

 }
}
```